# Alternative to iframe - Widget integration on third-party website

Tags: html, iframe

We have a widget and SaaS that displays content on our client websites via iframe code. We have been bumping into two issues with this integration: 
1- the iframe has all kinds of issues on mobile (as many people know) and loading is somewhat cumbersome. 
2- ADA compliance for websites is becoming more important in the US and iframe doesn't seem to be a compliant solution.

Is there an alternative to iframe that is recommended for highly interactive saas? Here is our live demo: https://www.imgoingtravel.com/live-demo

Thanks!

Comment: The Twitter, YouTube have 2 ways of embedding either with JavaScript or iframe.. if your widget is single page app (spa) don’t expect it to be ADA complaint even without iframe.